# can't start apache using xampp on mac

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I know it has been asked a lot, but i can't find the solution.
I am a mac user, and trying to start the apache server on the xampp, but it suddenly stops.
when i try "sudo apachectl stop" I get this error message:
"/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service".

when i look at the log of xampp:
when starting apache server:
"Starting Apache Web Server..."

but when it stops:
"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started"

yet, i can see that it stoped.

does anyone know how to solve it?
thank you!